# Does caja fix malformed HTML when using GAS createHtmlOutput() method?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-caja

In the following example the content "Here is some more text" is clearly outside the closing HTML tag. But when I run [the script as a web app and view the page source](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/114078821751650466152/albums/5860530893747714449/5860530895439758946) it's inside the closing tag. Is this because caja is sanitizing the malformed HTML? Why sanitize in this way instead of informing me of the error?

GAS code:

```
function doGet() {
    var ParagraphContent ='So much to do in so little time... '
    var HTMLToOutput = '<html><h1>A header</h1><p>' + ParagraphContent + '</p></html>';
    var HtmlAndMore = HTMLToOutput + 'Here is some more text';
    var it = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HtmlAndMore);
    Logger.log(HtmlAndMore)
    return it 
}
```

GAS script editor Logging Output:

```
<html><h1>A header</h1><p>So much to do in so little time... </p></html>Here is some more text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caja is designed to operate according to the HTML5 parsing algorithm (which is designed to codify browser vendors' consensus as to how HTML-in-the-wild must be parsed, and define a single correct parse-error-recovery strategy). That algorithm [effectively specifies](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-after-after-body-insertion-mode) that trailing content after `</html>` shall be inserted into the `<body>`, so the result you are seeing is what is specified.

However, it does also specify that that input is a parse error (which just means that it *may* be reported or *may* abort processing). Our latest technology ('ES5 mode') unfortunately does not yet make any attempt to report parse errors. I've [made a note](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1685) to fix that.

Comment: Please please please report the reasons in an output somewhere!  I know this is years old.  I can't be the only user that wants this, can I?